# chrome extension options change default popup.html 

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where the popup.html simply has an iframe that loads a page.

I want to allow users to select their language, and as I'm helping a charity do this each language page is very different as they need very different content based on the country!

Therefore, I can't just replace some of the fields like the google developer page example does; I need to change the page that is loaded in the iframe.

e.g. In my directory where the pages are stored I have english.html, german.html, spanish.html all of which are completely different pages.

By default the english.html page loads in the iframe, but the user should be able to go into the options file and select german so when they click on the extension the german.html loads by default every time.

Here is the jsfiddle showing what I currently have in the popup.html, and the popup.js:
http://jsfiddle.net/hemang2/EDV82/

You'll see the flickr API being called, but that's only there because I wasn't sure how to get rid of it!

So essentially my question is how to link the options file to change the default url loaded in the iframe.

Comment: "Any help would be much appreciated!" is not a good question. Please make your question more clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @MikeGrace sorry about that, I should have been more clear in my question. thanks for that link!

Answer (score 1):

Use the setPopup method: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup

It allows you to set any html file as your popup.